# Rails: Compare DateTime with Time.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, devise

I'm sure this is super easy but for some reason I just can't get it. I'm using `psql` and `devise`. I have a `user` model that has an `expiration` column. What I'm trying to do is, when the use logs in, have devise include the check for expiration as well.

I've overridden the `active_for_authentication?` method in the model to look like this:

```
def active_for_authentication? 
  super && expiration > Time.now.to_s(:db)
end
```

But now it's letting everyone in...

Help me Stackoverflow, you're my only hope!

**EDIT** I'm setting the expiration like this before the update where `amount` is a dynamic variable:

```
self.expiration = amount.weeks.from_now
```

**EDIT 2** Rails console says this:

`#<User:xxx> {:expiration => Mon, 24 Mar 2014 19:19:42 UTC +00:00}`

`2.0.0p0 :013 > Time.now
   2014-03-24 13:10:47 -0700`

Obviously they are different, which is why I assume they aren't working. What I'm trying to find out is if there is some simple conversion I'm missing e.g.: `.to_s(:db)` or if I have to do some kind of string compare.

Comment: why do you say that `self.expiration` is a `DateTime`? And why  `3.weeks.from_now > Time.now` is not going to return `true`?... am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Because the column in the DB is in DateTime format. (This may not be correct, but that's what I thought it was supposed to be)

Comment: Try `3.weeks.from_now.class` #=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, and also, `User.last.created_at.class` #=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare the strings, let it compare on Time.

`def active_for_authentication? 
  super && expiration.to_time > Time.now
end`

Comment: When I try this I get the following: `2.0.0p0 :016 > puts "true" if @user.expiration.to_time > Time.now
nil
2.0.0p0 :017 > puts @user.expiration.to_time
2014-03-24 19:19:42 UTC
nil
2.0.0p0 :018 > puts Time.now
2014-03-24 15:00:32 -0700
nil
2.0.0p0 :019 > `

Comment: Sorry about the formatting - basically it returns `nil` and not `true`. It looks like the difference is that `.to_time` is returning `UTC` and `Time.now` is returning `-0700`

Comment: That line won't work... try just entering this: `@user.expiration.to_time > Time.now`